# Configurar Visual Studio Code para JSX

Tags: reactjs

Hola amigos quiero saber como configuro el vs para jsx, ya que al guardar al etiquitas html se distorsionan por asi decirlo.

```html
        <
        div >
        <
        h1 > Aprendiendo React < /h1> <
        p > Hola Mundo < /p> <
        /div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actualmente puedes seleccionar el tipo de lenguaje JavaScript React,

Anteriormente mi solución era cambiar la codificación a C o similar para que no me lo reindentara.

Simplemente clic en el circulo rojo marcado. ( Abajo a la derecha )

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]